# Why would you put Identity Increment other than 1 in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, you can set the increment of an identity column other than 1.

In what situation would you do that?

[image]

Comment: if you have multiple master servers.... you can incriment by... for example 2.... 1 server does the even numbers and 1 does the un-even numbers.... while replicating you wont get any issues

Comment: Probably a better question for [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This might be a valid reason to do it, though I'm not sure.

We had an application spread out across two environments, one web server, one db server per environment.

Both environments were "active" at the same time and could have their tables written too.

Environment "A" had a identity of (1,2), and environment "B" had an identity of (2,2) - so that both A and B could have records written too without a risk of overlapping identities for when the data was merged together, there was no need to rejigger the IDs.

There are most definitely other ways to do this behavior without doing the above, but this was quick and easy.

Comment: FWIW, This may be nice for unique information (such as logs), but anything other than that and you're lending yourself to duplicate entries (and a lot of cleanup).

Comment: @BradChristie that is in fact what was being tracked in the tables :)